# For a given doc how to update and rename a field in mongodb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am going through a mongo cursor list and for selected documents that have a match in different collection, I am renaming a field say 'f' in the doc to 'g' and the adding a field named 'f' to the doc from another collection.

I'm new to pymongo but here's what I have in mind:
1)Rename

```
db.collection.update( { _id: 1 }, { $rename: { 'f': 'g' } } )
```

2)Update

```
db.collection.update_one({"$set": {"f": "new content"})
```

Is this correct and is there a better way to do this?
Would it be more efficient if I just update a dictionary and replace the doc with it?

Answer (score 0):

In your 1) example your first argument {_id: 1} is your filter, and any document that matches it will get renamed. In this case only the documents with _id equal to 1, probably not a practical example. You could filter on some field, say {'docname':'doc_42'}

In 2) I don't see a filter, there's no way of knowing which documents you want to modify.  The update_one only means the first document that matches the filter will be updated.

Reading in the whole document into a dictionary and writing it back is not generally the best idea. It requires a lot of network activity when documents get big.